# How to select random items from a set

Tags: javascript, json, random

I am trying to create a website that will call on my json file, and with that information randomize the results. So for example there are 100 items in my json file. So i am trying to figure out how from all that information I can make it only pick lets say 5 or 6 at random everytime the page is loaded.

This is my current script

```
function ajax_get_json(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();     
hr.open("GET", "lyrics.json", true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
   hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
       var data = JSON.parse (hr.responseText);
       var results = document.getElementById("results");
       results.innerHTML = "";
       for (var obj in data){ 
            results.innerHTML += data[obj].user;
        }
}
   }
hr.send(null); 
results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
```

}

I hope someone can help, I don't know much about this and am trying to learn for this artpiece that I am trying to create.

Heres a sample of what the json file looks like
its a sample from a drake song, the idea its to create random poems from a bunch of different lyrics eventually. I apologize that its says user and all of this may seem messy but I just mended things to work kind of how i needed to thats why its still says user.

```
{
"u1":{ "user":"I might be too strong out on compliments"},
"u2":{ "user":"Overdose on confidence"},
"u3":{ "user":"Started not to give a fuck and stopped fearing the consequence"},
"u4":{ "user":"Drinking every night because we drink to my accomplishments"},
"u5":{ "user":"Faded way too long I'm floating in and out of consciousness"},
"u6":{ "user":"And they sayin' I'm back, I'd agree with that"},
"u7":{ "user":"I just take my time with all this shit, I still believe in that"},
"u8":{ "user":"I had someone tell me I fell off, ooh I needed that"},
"u9":{ "user":"And they wanna see me pick back up, well where'd I leave it at"},
"u10":{ "user":"I know I exaggerated things, now I got it like that"}
}
```

the name of the file lyrics.json

So here is my current script updated with what you told me to change around

```
function getRandomItemsFrom(){
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("GET", "lyrics.json", true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
   hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
       var data = JSON.parse (hr.responseText);
       var results = document.getElementById("results");

       var lyricsArray = [];
       for ( prop in data ) {
           lyricsArray.push(data[prop].user);
        }

        var randomLyrics = getRandomItemsFrom(data.lyrics, 5);

        Results.innerHTML = "<div>" + data.lyrics.join("</div><div>") + "</div>";
}
   }
hr.send(null); 
results.innerHTML = "requesting...";
```

}

I guess I just have a couple more questions when you said I need to get the lyrics in to array do you mean they should be in essence in this format

```
{
 "items" : [
  {
   "lyrics" : "content1"
  },
  {
  "lyrics" : "content2"
  },
  {
  "lyrics" : "content3"
  }
 ]
}
```

So if my .json file was change to be like that in the script would I change where it is

```
lyricsArray.push(data[prop].user
```

to

```
lyricsArray.push(data[item].user
```

Comment: Uh...do you have an array of items and want to generate a random number to select an item?   That's not 'randomizing JSON'.  And why aren't you using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

Use a random number generator to generate a random number between 0 and *n* - 1 where *n* = the length of your JSON array:

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (n - 1)) + 1
```

Do that 5 or 6 times and use the values you get to access items from the array by index to display to the user.

As @CoryDanielson points out, you should also check to make sure you don't get the same number twice, which is more likely the smaller the array.

Incidentally, you should use `$.get` and `$('#results').html` from [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to avoid the low-level details of the XHR and the DOM.

Comment: Use `parseInt(Math.random() * n);` instead. If Math.random() produces .999999, your `Math.floor(...)` would result in 98 instead of 99.

Comment: you'll also have collisions though

Comment: Good call on the upper limit. Forgot the `+1`. A bad thing to do both with random numbers and a formal event.

Comment: Made the edit. I assumed a large enough playlist for that not to matter realistically, but you are right to point it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i am going to trying this out

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method:

First load all of your 100 items from the JSON file into your array in order.  Then use the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to shuffle the first five or six items in your array (you don't need to shuffle the rest since you don't use them.)  Lastly, use the first items in the part-shuffled array.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a set of unique items from an array. The length of the result set is dependent on the second parameter passed in.

It works by generating random numbers between 0 and the length of the array minus one. If the random number was not already used, it will grab the item at the random number's location in the array and store that to a results array. It does this until as many items as specified by the numberOfItems argument have been added to the results array and then returns the results array.

It becomes more and more inefficient as arr and numberOfItems grow closer together, especially if those numbers are large. Getting 5 random items from an array of 5 length is not very efficient, but shouldn't take too long, but getting 1000 random items from an array of 1000 would be very inefficient. For your use case (grabbing 5 random items from an array of 100 length) the inefficiencies with this code are negligible.

http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/S64Hy/

```
function getRandomItemsFrom(arr, numberOfItems) {
    if ( arr instanceof Array === false || arr.length === 0 ) return false;
    if ( numberOfItems === undefined || numberOfItems <= 0 ) return false;

    var results     = [],
        usedIndexes = {},
        randomIndex;

    while ( results.length !== numberOfItems ) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

        if ( usedIndexes.hasOwnProperty(randomIndex) === false ) {
            usedIndexes[randomIndex] = true;
            results.push(arr[randomIndex]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

### Usage:

```
var alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
getRandomItemsFrom(alphabet, 10);

result => ["v", "m", "e", "x", "l", "s", "b", "d", "w", "p"]
```

### Usage With Your Code:

First, add the `getRandomItemsFrom` function to the same file that has your above `ajax_get_json` function. Then change your code that handles retrieving the lyrics.json to something like this.

```
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
       var data = JSON.parse (hr.responseText);
       var results = document.getElementById("results");

       // get the lyrics in an array
       var lyricsArray = [];
       for ( prop in data ) {
           lyricsArray.push(data[prop].user);
       }

       // Get random lyrics           
       var randomLyrics = getRandomItemsFrom(data.lyrics, 5);

       results.innerHTML = "<div>" + data.lyrics.join("</div><div>") + "</div>";
}
```

Comment: So i'm still having some issue, most likely because I have never really done much of this but, I guess I'm not exactly sure where it is that i'm suppose to plug this in and or if this only works with a jQuery script or can it be plugged in to the one that I was using. The name of my json file is lyrics.json am I suppose to to plug hat in somewhere in to this script you sent me. Thanks for all the help btw!

Comment: Put it in the same file as your `ajax_get_json` function. Inside of the `onreadystatechange` function you can call `getRandomItemsFrom(data, 5)` to retrieve an array of 5 lyrics. You can then loop over the lyrics, add some HTML to them and put them into results.innerHTML. I'd have to see a sample of lyrics.json to give you a more precise answer though.

Comment: Hey updated and put a sample of what my json file looks like. Thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Comment: oh, that's oddly formatted data. You'll have to get the lyrics into an array first for this function to work. I'll update.

Comment: Updated, check out the section of my answer that says "Usage With Your Code" there's a few comments in there explaining the modifications i made

Comment: Yeah i know, I think thats why i've had a hard time i've just molded what I learned from tutorials to try and fit what I want to do. Im going to update my current script in how i edited with the update you gave me.